# 3D model not casting shadows in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow, 3d-model

I am importing a *glTF* model into [ThreeJS](https://threejs.org) and have a [PlaneGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/PlaneGeometry) acting as a ground. I need the model to cast shadows onto the plane/ground.

[image]

[image]

I've tried enabling

```
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
```

on

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
```

I also have 2 lights:

```
const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x444444);
hemiLight.position.set(0, 10, 0);
scene.add( hemiLight );
const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
dirLight.position.set(0, 0, 10);
dirLight.castShadow = true;
dirLight.shadow.camera.top = 200;
dirLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -200;
dirLight.shadow.camera.left = - 200;
dirLight.shadow.camera.right = 200;
dirLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
dirLight.shadow.camera.far = 500;
scene.add( dirLight );
```

Final code

```css
body
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div#container canvas
{
  cursor: grab;
}

div#container canvas:active
{
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Import 3D Model into Three JS</title>
  
  <script type="module" defer>
  import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/build/three.module.js';

  import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';    // for .glb and .gltf.glb
  // import { OBJLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';   // for .obj

  import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

  const container = document.querySelector('div#container');

  const path_to_model = './ImportModel/Mini-Game Variety Pack/Models/gltf/tree_forest.gltf.glb';
  const loader = new GLTFLoader();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 500);

  // Add lights
  const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x444444);
  hemiLight.position.set(0, 10, 0);
  scene.add( hemiLight );
  const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
  dirLight.position.set(0, 0, 10);
  dirLight.castShadow = true;
  dirLight.shadow.camera.top = 200;
  dirLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -200;
  dirLight.shadow.camera.left = - 200;
  dirLight.shadow.camera.right = 200;
  dirLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
  dirLight.shadow.camera.far = 500;
  scene.add( dirLight );

  // Make renderer
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true
  });

  // Make transparent
  renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0);

  // Set it to window size
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  // Force shadows
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

  // Helper (optional)
  // const camera_helper = new THREE.CameraHelper(dirLight.shadow.camera);
  // scene.add(camera_helper);

  // Double quality
  const quality = 2;
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth * quality, window.innerHeight * quality, false);

  // Add mouse movement
  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  // Add floor (plane)
  const plane_geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
  const plane_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffff00,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  });
  const plane = new THREE.Mesh(
    plane_geometry,
    plane_material
  );
  plane.rotation.x = 1.5708;
  plane.castShadow = true;
  plane.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(plane);

  console.log(plane);

  // Import glTF
  loader.load(path_to_model, function (gltf)
  {
    //gltf.scene.position.y = -5;
    //gltf.scene.center();
    //gltf.scene.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);

    // Make it cast shadows
    gltf.scene.castShadow = true;
    gltf.scene.traverse(function(node)
    {
      if (node.isMesh)
      {
        node.castShadow = true;
        //node.receiveShadow = true;
      }
    });

    console.log(gltf);

    console.log('Adding glTF model to scene...');
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    console.log('Model added.');

    console.log('Moving camera 5z...');
    camera.position.z = 5;
    console.log('Camera moved.');
    }, undefined, function (error)
    {
      console.error(error);
    });

  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  function animate()
  {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  animate();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update:** changed `MeshBasicMaterial` to `MeshPhongMaterial` in plane as suggested by [@Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68148511/3d-model-not-casting-shadows-in-threejs?noredirect=1#comment120445899_68148511).

Comment: I’m not too familiar with three.js but if MeshBasicMaterial can’t receive light then maybe it can’t have shadows casted on it. Try MeshPhongMaterial or one of the other options.

Comment: @Justin the tree still doesn't cast shadow on the plane, but at least the plane casts a shadow underneath itself now

Comment: Consider to debug the shadow camera of the directional light via `THREE.CameraHelper`. Both the shadow casting and receiving object should be inside the visualized frustum. The frustum itself should be as tight as possible. Use this code: `scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( dirLight.shadow.camera ) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hemisphere light seems to be the main culprit. If you change the position of it you can start getting shadow. Most likely it was casting light everywhere thus drowning out any chance of shadows. Moving it away from the plane helped. Also the `dirLight.shadow.camera.top/bottom/left/right` are all too high. I used 2, vice 200, along with changing the hemi light and it seems to be working.

HTML

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Import 3D Model into Three JS</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div#container canvas
{
  cursor: grab;
}

div#container canvas:active
{
  cursor: grabbing;
}
```

JS

```
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/build/three.module.js";

import { GLTFLoader } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"; // for .glb and .gltf.glb
// import { OBJLoader } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';   // for .obj

import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

const container = document.querySelector("div#container");

const path_to_model =
  "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1376484/stacy_lightweight.glb";
const loader = new GLTFLoader();

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.01,
  500
);

// Add lights
const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x444444);
hemiLight.position.set(20, 20, 10);
scene.add(hemiLight);
const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
dirLight.position.set(-10, 20, 6);
dirLight.castShadow = true;
dirLight.shadow.camera.top = 2;
dirLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -2;
dirLight.shadow.camera.left = -2;
dirLight.shadow.camera.right = 2;
dirLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
dirLight.shadow.camera.far = 500;
scene.add(dirLight);

// Make renderer
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  alpha: true
});

// Make transparent
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0);

// Set it to window size
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

// Force shadows
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

// Helper (optional)
// const camera_helper = new THREE.CameraHelper(dirLight.shadow.camera);
// scene.add(camera_helper);

// Double quality
const quality = 2;
renderer.setSize(
  window.innerWidth * quality,
  window.innerHeight * quality,
  false
);

// Add mouse movement
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// Add floor (plane)
const plane_geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10);
const plane_material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0xffff00,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
const plane = new THREE.Mesh(plane_geometry, plane_material);
plane.rotation.x = 1.5708;
plane.castShadow = true;
plane.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(plane);

console.log(plane);

//scene.add(box)

// Import glTF
loader.load(
  path_to_model,
  function (gltf) {
    //gltf.scene.position.y = -5;
    //gltf.scene.center();
    //gltf.scene.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);

    // Make it cast shadows
    gltf.scene.castShadow = true;
    gltf.scene.traverse(function (node) {
      if (node.isMesh) {
        node.castShadow = true;
        //node.receiveShadow = true;
      }
    });

    console.log(gltf);

    console.log("Adding glTF model to scene...");
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    console.log("Model added.");

    console.log("Moving camera 5z...");
    camera.position.z = 5;
    console.log("Camera moved.");
  },
  undefined,
  function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
);

container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();
```